# Presenting labels in raster format in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, geotiff-tiff, rasterization

I'm creating a raster map of a large city in ArcMap 9.3 which will be used in a third-party software.  My problem is that I need to find a way to include labels of street names in my output.  I have a shapefile containing the roads of interest, which I can convert to raster for export to the third party software.  However, I can't figure out how to convert the street name labels to raster as well.

I'd like the labels to be small (i.e., readable at about 1:20k scale) so they don't clutter up the map too much when it is zoomed out.  The best "solution" I have come up with so far is to turn on and adjust the labels correctly, then export the map as a geoTIFF.  The drawback is that I can only seem to export the visible extent of my file.  Following this workflow, I'd export the sections individually, then mosaic them together into a new TIFF, with labels.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Also, the third-party software has the capability to read shapefiles.  So, my other thought was to somehow convert the labels to polygons, which could then be overlaid on the raster map in the third-party software to provide the label functionality.  However, I can't seem to get that to work either.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its over 9 years old using defunct software.